# When images are blocked in a browser, are they downloaded?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

When images are blocked, are they simply not rendered or are they prevented from being downloaded?

In Google Chrome 12 I've set `Content Settings > Images > Don't show any images.`

Comment: Please provide some more information about the browser and the type of blockade you use.

Comment: Google chrome 12; content settings>images>don't show any images

Comment: As far as I know chrome 12 is a beta version, thus I am no absolutely sure about this, but I think the images are not downloaded. To become sure about this you may search the chrome cash for .bmp/.jpeg/etc files.

Comment: Trivial to find if you run a sniffer, since at least HTTP content is not encrypted when being sent through the wire.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how they are blocked.

If they are blocked at a firewall or similar content filter, they are not downloaded

If they are blocked by ABP on firefox, they are not downloaded.

On chrome, on older versions they were downloaded and hidden. On newer ones they are not downloaded

Comment: Pretty sure ABP prevents downloads. The page size certainly decreases with it enabled.

Comment: ... what i said is the exact opposite of what i meant to say... correcting!